# Using django-filter to filter by CharFilter on foreign key

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-filter

I'm attempting to use django-filter to display a list of filtered Orders.  Each order has a device field which is a ForeignKey, like so:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
    BLACK = 'BLACK'
    CYAN = 'CYAN'
    MAGENTA = 'MAGENTA'
    YELLOW = 'YELLOW'
    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        (BLACK, 'black'),
        (CYAN, 'cyan'),
        (MAGENTA, 'magenta'),
        (YELLOW, 'yellow'),
    )
    toner = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=COLOR_CHOICES)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField('order triggered date')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-order_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.toner
```

The default filter type is the ModelChoiceFilter, but that displays a really long list of possibly thousands of devices.  I want to be able to filter with text using CharFilter like the following in my filters.py:

```
class OrderFilter(df.FilterSet):
    device = df.CharFilter(lookup_type='icontains')
    order_date = df.DateFilter()

class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = ['device', 'toner', 'order_date']
    order_by = ['order_date']
```

However, I'm presented with the following error upon trying to filter via a typed text on the device filter field.

```
Traceback:
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py" in inner 
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/auto_toner/auto_toner/views.py" in OrderView
  50.   return render(request, 'auto_toner/order_filter.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  89.             using=using)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  115.                         template_name, context, context_instance, dirs, dictionary)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in render_to_string
  221.             return t.render(context_instance)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  96.     return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  96.     return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/endless_pagination/templatetags/endless.py" in render
  296.         objects = self.objects.resolve(context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  787.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "/home/mwood/auto_toner_django/venv_auto_toner/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  839.                                                        (bit, current))  # missing attribute

Exception Type: VariableDoesNotExist at /devices/orders/
Exception Value: Failed lookup for key [qs] in '<auto_toner.filters.OrderFilter object at 0x7fd721fa32e8>'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or if there's a better way to go about this? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you'd have an easier time setting this up with Q objects. http://toastdriven.com/blog/2008/nov/09/quick-dirty-search-django/

Comment: That's possible, I will look that over, but I'm already using django-filters on another page of my site and so I wanted the look/feel to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, using q objects did turn out to be simpler and have less dependencies once I spent the time to do it.  I actually learned how to do this easiest from a post [here](http://julienphalip.com/post/2825034077/adding-search-to-a-django-site-in-a-snap), which describes implementing a simple searching function with q objects.  Using the same principle to grab the request parameters from the URL, I was easily able to come up with a sorting/filtering function.

To prevent link rot I'm posting the contents of the link here.

> Search is a feature that is – or at least, should be – present on most sites containing dynamic or large content.
>
> There are a few projects around to tackle that. Here’s a non-exhaustive list: djangosearch, django-search (with a dash), django-sphinx.
>
> Those search engines are great, but they seem like overkill if you just need a simple search feature for your CMS or blog.
>
> To deal with that, I’ve come up with a generic and simple trick. All you need is copy/paste the following snippet anywhere in your project:

```
import re

from django.db.models import Q

def normalize_query(query_string,
                findterms=re.compile(r'"([^"]+)"|(\S+)').findall,
                normspace=re.compile(r'\s{2,}').sub):
''' Splits the query string in invidual keywords, getting rid of unecessary spaces
    and grouping quoted words together.
    Example:

    >>> normalize_query('  some random  words "with   quotes  " and   spaces')
    ['some', 'random', 'words', 'with quotes', 'and', 'spaces']

'''
return [normspace(' ', (t[0] or t[1]).strip()) for t in findterms(query_string)] 

def get_query(query_string, search_fields):
''' Returns a query, that is a combination of Q objects. That combination
    aims to search keywords within a model by testing the given search fields.

'''
query = None # Query to search for every search term        
terms = normalize_query(query_string)
for term in terms:
    or_query = None # Query to search for a given term in each field
    for field_name in search_fields:
        q = Q(**{"%s__icontains" % field_name: term})
        if or_query is None:
            or_query = q
        else:
            or_query = or_query | q
    if query is None:
        query = or_query
    else:
        query = query & or_query
return query
```

> What the above does is generate a django.db.models.Q object (see doc) to search through your model, based on the query string and on the model’s fields that you want to search. Importantly, it also analyses the query string by splitting out the key words and allowing words to be grouped by quotes. For example, out of the following query string…
>
> '  some random  words "with   quotes  " and   spaces'
>   …the words 'some', 'random', 'words', 'with quotes', 'and', 'spaces' would actually be searched. It performs an AND search with all the given words, but you could easily customise it to do different kinds of search.
>
> Then, your search view would become as simple as:

```
def search(request):
query_string = ''
found_entries = None
if ('q' in request.GET) and request.GET['q'].strip():
    query_string = request.GET['q']

    entry_query = get_query(query_string, ['title', 'body',])

    found_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entry_query).order_by('-pub_date')

return render_to_response('search/search_results.html',
                      { 'query_string': query_string, 'found_entries': found_entries },
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

> And that’s it! I use this on a site that has about 10,000 news items and it works pretty fast…
>
> Now you have no excuse not to add a search box to your site! ;)